# connectedAccessories returns empty array but the bluetooth device is connected

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I'm trying to get the connected printer (Zebra QLn220, QLn320) through Bluetooth with the next snippet of code:

```
EAAccessoryManager *sam = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];
NSArray * connectedAccessories = [sam connectedAccessories];
```

This works the 99% of times but after a lot of work printing through the method `[ZebraPrinterConnection write:data error:error]`, the connectedAccessories starts failing and returns an empty array. This can't be solved even stopping the app and starting again. But if I turn off the printer and turn on it again, this code works again.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the SDK and the problem was solved

Comment: The Zebra SDK, the old one was the cause of the disconnection issues